# Fever and diarrhea in 4 month old kitten

Tags: cats, behavior, health, diseases

I have a 4 month old kitten which was very active and playful. However, it seems sick as of two days ago. It's eating much less food and sleeping all the time. It has an increased body temperature, and diarrhea, which is not severe.

Please suggest medications or any help which can be done now. I am looking for a natural remedy due to the unavailability of vets amidst the covid outbreak.

Comment: The remedy is a vet. This is an emergency situation, and vets are available for emergencies.